# Library is using wrong R file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I package a library project as aar-file and include it in a different project via gradle.
Now it seems like the library project is using a wrong R file which leads to NullPointerExceptions.

#### Library Project (packaged as aar):

- SomeFragment

  ```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = new View(getActivity());
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_some, container, false);
  }
  ```

#### My Project

- MyFragment extends SomeFragment

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  L.d("ExtendedFragment - onCreateView");

  return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  }
  ```

#### R values:

- build/generated/source/r/debug/com.example.myapp/R.java - `fragment_some=0x7f030005;`
- build/generated/source/r/test/debug/com/example/mylibrary/R.java - `fragment_some=0x7f030005;`
- build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.example/mylibrary/version/R.txt - `fragment_some 0x7f030000`

While debugging I realized that in the Library the Id of the R.txt file is handed to the Inflater. The problem is that the Inflater uses the R.java, mentioned above, to resolve the ressource, gets the wrong ressource and inflates therefore a wrong layout which in the following leads to Exceptions.

#### What could be the reason for this behaviour?

- Is the R.txt file incorrectly generated? What purpose has the R.txt file?
- Do I have to set the Context or the R file somewhere in Code?
- Or could it be in the buildscript of the project, that it might not include the lib corretly?

## Update 20.10.2014

I could not find a solution yet but I included the libraryproject directly as module into my project and everythings works fine. So it seems like it is a problem how gradle resolves the aar file.

Comment: first of all did you try to clean both projects and build em again?

Comment: yes I tried this, any other clues?

Comment: @Sven ... Can you please accept an answer, if the question is resolved

Answer (score 2):

### Steps

1. `Clean` your project and `build` it again
2. Check whether the `R.java` file is generated or not
   If the `R.java` is not generated there is possibility that there is a error in your project most probably in `xml file`
3. Find out from the imports which `R.java` is imported whether it is `import android.R` or `import android.projectName.R`. So the correct one is `import android.projectName.R`. Android automatically does this but sometimes you have to do this manually

Comment: Thank you so much. For some reason eclipse changed my import and R was from android instead of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Resources need to be uniquely named/identified. This is actually a convenience if you want to override a previously defined resource. For example, you want to change a layout that exists in a library, and customize it when you implement it in your app. Like if you create a library for "search" then you want to use that library across several projects and change the look by using custom icons or changing background colors. You can create icons with the same name and those will be used when the project is built.

In order to avoid this you need to uniquely name the resource in the current project.

As an aside, this also means that if you ever build a library for general distribution you should be sure to create resource names that are unlikely to conflict with the developer's selection of resource names.

In particular, you have a resource named `fragment_some` that is assigned the same reference value `0x7f030005` - this creates a collision that is resolved by referencing the most recently created R file.

Comment: I checked it again and the resource-ids of the library are not overwritten by the project. They are unique.

Comment: My answer is not that the resource ids are "overwritten" - they are assigned the same value and referenced at compile time by the most recently written resource file. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Check the import you must have by mistake imported the android.R instead of com.yourproject.R